# Can I send SMS from Salesforce's Marketing Cloud without buying license?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

I am working on a POC wherein I am supposed to send some SMSes through Marketing Cloud. Can I do that with a free account?
If yes, then please guide me from where to do that. Thanks!

Comment: Is it a trial account or a partner account?

Comment: Yes, it did. I am sorry that I forgot to accept your answer. I just did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer:**

If its a trial account then no. If its a Partner account then maybe

Partner accounts are not provisioned with SMS accounts. You can have the functionality enabled (ie configured lists, add sms sends journeys) but no messages will be sent.

**Explanation:**

I spoke to an account exec about this, and the reasoning behind it is that a while back, a partner had sent over 1 million SMS messages, leaving SF with a massive bill to foot.

**Solution:**

If sending the message is strong requirement, you can have a conversation about a "severely discounted" paid account. This is what partners that need to send sms messages have.